# itemViewClassBinding in a collectionView

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to create a reusable component which consist of a textfield and under the textfield, i want to have a collectionView to display a filtered list of elements.

My problem is that I want `itemViewClass` of the `containerView` to be customized when creating the component. Currently, I pass a parameter `listItemView` to the container view and declare
`itemViewClassBinding: 'parentView.listItemView'` instead of having an hardcoded templates.

This leads me to a problem where Ember assert that `itemViewClass` must be an instance of Ember.View:

> Uncaught Error: assertion failed: itemViewClass must be a subclass of
>   Ember.View, not function () {

Did anybody ran into a similar problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-classing your `ContainerView` class is one option. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ethan_selzer/kcjzw/240/

This pastie may be a little easier to read: http://pastie.org/4256407

Ethan

Comment: Thank you! I came up with the same solution as you. My problem is that I was creating the views in my container view instead of extending them. When I changed to extend it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I have created this functionality very recently in my ember app. The way I did it was by binding to a controller property. When the user types in the textfield it needs to set the filter text as a controller property. Then your controller will have another property that observes the filter field text property and produces a filtered list of the content data based on the filter text. Then your filtered view would be bound to that filtered content of the controller instead of the usual (all) content. This way your two views don't need to know about each other and the controller provides the data.

Comment: Thank you, I already have the working code. My only problem is providing a dynamic itemViewClass for my collectionView. If I harcode a certain itemViewClass then it works fine. I just want to make it scale at a higher level. If I could provide a basic itemViewClass and override it when needed than I could use this component for every case. Here's the best version that I can't make it work. http://pastie.org/4251637